# How to change the content of div on the basis of what is selected in the menu

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Please bear with me, this question is very crude. I'm new to Ember js, and have got a lotta confusion between views controllers templates routes. I have this basic requirement, to have a menu on the left, with item `users`, `organizations`. and a div in the center, As of now, when i click users, i have given a link to `/users` route. for organizations `/organizations` route, which is a different template. I want to display them in the centered div. Not sure how to do that. I think it has got something to do with child views, but find myself numb in beginning. I just need help in the workflow of how to achieve this.

**EDIT**:

Here is the basic code, I have this page called `home`. Template `home.hbs`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li>
            {{#link-to 'users'}} Users{{/link-to}}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{#link-to 'organizations'}} Organizations {{/link-to}}
        </li>
</ul>

<div class="summary-width span10" id="home-container">
</div>
```

Similarly there is `users.hbs` and `organization.hbs`.

When a user clicks on users link, i want the users template to be displayed in `home-container` div. organizations template otherwise.

Comment: You could give the DIV an ID and set the innerHTML with JavaScript.

Comment: @durbnpoisn: This is the line that I wrote in the action on click of the users link, ` Ember.$("#dashboard-widgets-container").innerHTML = "Users";` but it does not seem to do anything, no text "Users" got printed in the div

Comment: @Inquisitive if you have to do things with jquery like you are doing here, you are completely missing the point of Ember and not utilizing the framework at all. read <a href="http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/concepts/core-concepts/">this</a>

Comment: @sunrize920 yeah, that's what I said, I read those concepts, but got a lot confused of how the DOM is rendered. How I will render in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you do what you are describing with routes. This is your `application.hbs` ie the template associated with the application route and controller.

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li>
            {{#link-to 'users'}} Users{{/link-to}}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{#link-to 'organizations'}} Organizations {{/link-to}}
        </li>
</ul>

<div class="summary-width span10" id="home-container">
{{outlet}}
</div>
```

you would then have a router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('organizations');
  this.route('users');
});

export default Router;
```

`{{link-to 'users'}}` will enter the users route, call all the hooks, create the controller if it doesn't already exist, set the model on the controller, and render the `users.hbs` template into the application template's outlet. The `home.hbs` you are describing should be renamed to `index.hbs` because by default Ember renders your `index.hbs` template into the outlet when `/` is accessed (or whatever your base url is). Sure, its possible to make a different template be the default but that involves more code so just change your `home.hbs` to `index.hbs`

Edit:
add this to your router:

```
this.resource('home', function(){
      this.route('organizations');
      this.route('users');
  });
```

if those routes are truly nested below your home route. Your link to's would need to change to `{{#link-to 'home.organizations'}}`

If you don't nest like this, then `{{#link-to 'users'}}` will render the `users.hbs` file into the application's outlet. That's just how Ember and the router work.

If you can't nest for some reason, then change the `link-to` to `actions`, make the `{{outlet}}` a named outlet like `{{outlet 'named'}}` and in your `routes/home.js` actions hash, make actions that `this.renderTemplate()` into the named outlet. Look at the api for exactly how to do this

Comment: I have a different application template, with header and footer, this is the home dashboard page. the other pages are like login etc I can not rename it to index hbs.

Comment: so then you need to make users and organizations be nested routes of the home route

Comment: okay got it, this is what i needed, thnx. Use this comment in the answer

Comment: trying out with the second method, render just renders the template, if the users template has a call to display the names of all the users then it has that fetched in model, but does not print anything, except the plain template